# Disable button if form is invalid OR after click

Tags: html, angular, ionic4

I want to disable the button if the form is invalid OR after the user click it, but not both.

How can I add 2 statements inside the quotes?

I tried it like this but it's not working:

```
<form [formGroup]="weightForm" (submit)="saveWeight(); clicked=true; " novalidate>
    <ion-button expand="block" type="submit" [disabled]="!weightForm.valid && clicked==true" >Submit</ion-button>
</form>
```

Like that only the after click disable works.

Comment: use `weightForm.dirty or weightForm.touched` , whatever suits you better instead of your clicked parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define a property submitted in Ts file like:

```
     submitted = false;
     onSubmit() {
     this.submitted = true;
     if (this.weightForm.invalid) { // stop here if form is invalid
      return;
    }
     this.updateInfo();
  }
      <form [formGroup]="weightForm" (ngSubmit)="submitted && onSubmit()" novalidate> 
     or disabled="{{submitted}}"
```